# Extract specific URL from a string with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, string, url, google-apps-script

I have a string like:

```
link|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755|
link_of_pdf|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.pdf|
link_of_xml|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.xml|
```

I need to extract the second URL:

```
https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.pdf
```

Each URL is contained between 2 sticks and changes with each script execution, but the extension is always the same (* .pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve `https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.pdf` from the following string using Google Apps Script.

  ```
  const str = `link|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755|
  link_of_pdf|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.pdf|
  link_of_xml|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.xml|`;
  ```

For this, how about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `split` is used. In this case, when the position of the URL you want is the same, this can be used.

#### Sample script:

```js
const str = `link|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755|
link_of_pdf|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.pdf|
link_of_xml|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.xml|`;

const res = str.split("|")[3];
console.log(res)
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, regex is used. In this case, when the URL you want is enclosed by `link_of_pdf|` and `|`, this can be used.

#### Sample script:

```js
const str = `link|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755|
link_of_pdf|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.pdf|
link_of_xml|https://www.nubefact.com/cpe/3a5c76ea-9447-4f34-9b90-7f514345cbf8-474b0936-c936-49f5-acb6-9e94102ce755.xml|`;

const res = str.match(/link_of_pdf\|(.+)\|/)[1];
console.log(res)
```

### References:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Perfect, I had been working with a code similar to your first solution, but the second one assures me the same result even if I changed the position of the URL. Thank you.

Comment: @J. Kenneth Reátegui B. Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.